# In Wild Wild West, what kills "Metal Head"?

Tags: plot-explanation, wild-wild-west

Near the end of the movie, after they boarded the spider, *Jim West* (Will Smith) fight some henchmen of *Loveless*. When comes the turn of *"Metal Head"*, *Jim* discovers that the guy is *entirely* armored and surrenders. *"Metal Head"* then raises his weapon to strike and... is electrocuted?

[image: "Metallo" being electrocuted]

The way that *Jim* just calmly steps aside and lets the guy fall to his death tells me that it's what he had planned all along. But I really don't understand what happened. As far as I can see, he is not touching any kind of wire around.

[image: "Metallo" falls]

[Youtube video of the scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EPJGFrntGfU&t=2m2s)

Missing CGI? Continuity error? Or did I simply miss something?

Comment: I have nothing to back this up, and while I've wondered this for a while the only explanation I've been able to come up with is he hits some kind of "live-wire" with the wrench when he lifts it above his head to hit James West. The angle of the shot is weird, so it's possible the wire was just outside of the shot or at an angle we can't see, but it would explain the sparks and smoke.

Comment: I always thought his brain simply short-circuited because he was angry or something. Which is an exceedingly lame resolution to that fight, but this *is* 'Wild Wild West' after all. (In the script Jim just tricks him into falling off the train.)

Comment: Derek Mears as ***Metal Head***. That's the characters name.

Comment: Some website says that the two pipes next to him are electrical conductors. Add Metal Head and the Wrench, electricity shorted through him. But without any visual effects to confirm that, it does seem like a huge continuity issue.

Comment: No real evidence here, but it could be that the repeated knocks to the head dislodged something in the internals, and then the anger and motion to raise the wrench then caused a short inside.  That's the only thing I can think of given the localised electrocution in his head

Comment: I don't think I remember noticing this when I first watched this film, but the pants Will Smith is wearing are not the same as like what Robert Conrad wore in the original TV series. Conrad's West was well known for tight, very tight, ex-tremely tight, pants. _"I’m not debonair. I’m not suave. I did wear tight pants, though, because I found out that it worked.” — Robert Conrad"_

Answer (score 3):

I always thought, Metal Head is touching some kind of electricity, but:

1. The two copper tubes are not for electrical means but are carrying steam, probably for the hydraulic system of the spider (I suggest this, because after Loveless shoots at West but misses him, he hits the tubes instead, the steam escapes and the hydraulical system of the spider collapses because of negative pressure).
2. There is some kind of net above the two, but if you look carefully, Metal Head is not touching it whith the wrench.

So, whats left, is that the hits West placed on the head of Metal head are seemingly not harming him, but then, as he wants to hit West and "strain" his head, then his "system" malfunctions because the hits really have harmed him. My evidences for this theory:

1. The light and smoke is coming out of Metal Head and not from outside.
2. It remembers to the scene in Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the Crystal Skull, where Indy hits the officer at the end a lot of times and you think, that the officer prepares to fight back, but actually the officer is knocked out because he falls down without any additional hit from Indy.
3. So it's a Hollywood-typical thing to surprise the audience.
   I hope this helps!;-)

Comment: There's nothing in the novelisation or either version of the script to describe what happened other than that he attacked West and then fell

Answer (score 1):

This isn't explained, even in [the script](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Wild-Wild-West.html):

> ```
>   West, exhausted, turns and sees...
>
>   METAL HEAD
>
>   all seven feet of him. The top of his head is a metal
>   plate. Extending downward, encircling his eyes. West
>   soaks him in, sighs.
>
>                              WEST
>                Uh, I just threw my shovel out.
>                So this really isn't fair. If
>                you don't mind, I'd like to...
>
>   West, at lightning speed, throws a sucker-punch/spin-
>   ning back-fist to Metal Head's jaw... PING! That one
>   really hurt... West's hand, that is. Metal Head isn't
>   fazed a bit. West throws another shot, this time to
>   the gut... PING! Then a kick to the groin... PING!!!
>
>                                WEST
>                         (incredulous)
>                Noooo.
>
>   Metal Head has had enough. He effortlessly picks West
>   up by his lapels and flings him across the room. West
>   tumbles, and lands right next to...
>
>   WRENCH
>
>   He picks it up and starts swinging! A shot to the body
>   ... PING! Then another... PING! Then another... PINGGGG!
>   Metal Head lurches forward, absorbing each blow with not
>   so much as a twitch of the eye. West furries... PING!
>   PING! PING! PING!... nothing! He goes for the head...
>   PINNNNNNGGGG!... nothing! West is out of time. He's been
>   backed up as far as he can go. His heels are dangling
>   over the mouth of the beast, a thousand feet above the
>   rocky cliff.
>
>                                WEST
>                Sorry.
>
>                                                  (CONTINUED)
>
>    WILD WILD WEST - Rev. 4/9/99                              109E.  
>
>
>
>    Metal head grunts, grimaces and pitches forward, toward
>    West, slowly but menacingly... West braces himself.
>
>                               METAL HEAD
>                 Urrrrrrrrrrggggghhh!!!
>
>    West side-steps and Metal Head falls face first into
>    the open air.
>
>                                WEST
>                         (downward)
>                 You guys just don't get out
>                 enough.
>
>                                                  CUT TO:
> ```

Earlier in the script, James fights Knife Guy and Shovel Guy, and how they are killed are explained more clearly. Not so much Metal Head.

Answer (score 0):

Got this answer off moviemistakes.com:

> The "man with a metal head" is obviously a Cyborg. A Cyborg with an iron pipe who's just walked between two large Copper Conductors. He's dead.

Answer (score -2):

inside metal head is electricity so when west gave him metal bar meatal head touched this metal bar with his both hands so his electricity killed him.

[image]

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is not valid. After all Metal Head worked for Dr. Lovelace and in the Dr's Tarantula steam transport, which was made almost entirely of metal. If the simple fact of touching metal were enough to kill Metal Head, he'd have died long before meeting West.